# How Change Root Directory in git?

Tags: git, gitlab, version-control, root

As a beginner, I started to learn full-stack with personal projects. before going to the backend I started frontend development using react. I created login pages and other dashboards using React and used multiple arrays as a database. right now my frontend project is done and I started to go with the backend using (express, MySQL, and cors). before I start the project I create a git repository and I need to change that git repository folder into the previous folder.

```
Food Delivery App  2. I need to change root directory here
  - Frontend -- 1. I start my git repository in here(git init)
  - Backend
```

I watched a few videos and articles and followed their guidance. but I can't find a solution. even 2nd time I tried my whole code was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move your `.git` folder to the folder that you want to be your root directory. Also move fiels such as `.gitmodules`, `.gitignore`, `.gitattributes`

Commit all your changes

```
git add -A
git commit
```

Comment: This seems like supremely dubious advice. There are many scenarios where this will fail more or less spectacularly.